# GeoJSON layer will not display anything in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have been trying to load some point data from geojson into openlayers 3. Eventually I would like to load the features from a url with the data, But I cannot get a single point to show from a hardcoded object.

Do I need to inform openlayers 3 about epsg:27700 in some way?
Or what am I missing.

Loading the same layer from a WMS seems to work fine, but I would like to get a WFS to work as well.

```
var geojson = {
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"totalFeatures":1,
"features":[
    {
        "type":"Feature",
        "id":"schools",
        "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[315850.99712308607,176054.0042378275]
        },
        "geometry_name":"geometry",
        "properties":{
            "ID":1,"Name":"High School","POINT_X":315850.997098,"POINT_Y":176054.004321
        }
    }
],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700"}}}

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
title: 'Schools',
source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojson, { dataProjection: 'EPSG:27700', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3286' })
}),
style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 10,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)'}),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red', width: 1})
    })
})
```

});

Comment: Could you expand on what exactly is going wrong? What type of browser are you using? Is the basemap displaying? ect

Comment: The base map is loading fine, using a variety of them and a custom layer switcher and that all works.

The I have a plethora of layers I am requesting from my geoserver setup and they all work a charm in said layer switcher.

I though I was doing really well with this and then thought I will load in some geojson data, from the same layer on on the geoserver and nothing displays, no errors and I am unsure how to move forward.

The above hardcoded var is just a sample feature of the layer, picked out from the geojson string geoserver returns.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to load WFS data in place of a WMS map image, now seems so wrong.

If I had gotten this working, I would have had to re-specify styles for it in openlayers 3, rendering any Geoserver-side SLD styling pointless.

If you are asking Geoserver for WFS data for a layer, simply to display, lets say a whole country's worth of data in Openlayers, like I was - it is most likely you want to rethink where you are going.